# Solution of the linear ODE of nth order

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I can solve linear ODEs with some defined order but can't solve the following differential equation. I tried my best to find a way to solve it but I couldn't. Please help me.

$$ x^{2}\,y^{n}-3\,x\,y'+3\,y=2\,x^{4}\,e^{x} $$

The question asked is "Convert the equation in the standard form and then solve using the Method of Variation of Parameters?"

`Note`This equation appeared in a standard test.

Comment: Is it $y^n$ or $y^{(n)}$?

Comment: This is very certainly an error in transcription. The original was $y''$, perhaps hand-written, and the double prime was falsely recognized as $n$, the same as a triple prime comes up occasionally as $m$. With that correction you have a standard Euler-Cauchy DE with a not-so-standard right side. Variation-of-constants required.

Comment: it is $$ y^n $$

Comment: Is it unsolvable for y^n

Comment: Yes, that need not be your error. Some bad photo-copy get transcribed without checking if the type of equation is still in the context of the exam or scope of course, ... If you recognize such, you should ask for clarification, as that is a power, not a derivative. Or you write down the corrected task, with an explicit remark, and solve then that.

Comment: Thanks all for the response.